# Cypress doesn't recognize a class when it actually exist in the element

Tags: cypress

I have an element that I have to assert if it is disabled, I took the element by Id and apply a `.parentsUntil` searching for a div with the class that indicates it is disabled.

When it arrives to that div cypress doesn't recognize the class even when the class is there

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The result of `.parentsUntil()` does not include the element you specified (strangely)

Ref [parentsUntil](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/parentsuntil#Syntax)

> Get all ancestors of each DOM element in a set of matched DOM elements up to, **but not including**, the element provided.

So, just add one more `.parent()`

```js
cy.get(...)
  .parentsUntil('.ant-select-disabled')
  .eq(0)
  .parent()
  .should('have.class', 'ant-select-disabled')
```

Comment: Already solve it, in the should function you dont have to put the period on the class selector, just the class name.

Comment: True! I missed that.